# How to make directional block in Minecraft 1.12.2 modding?

Tags: java, minecraft, minecraft-forge

I've been developing Minecraft 1.12.2 mod for few months by now. I wanted to make directional block. The block is black and purple cube (when placed, in the hand is has texture). The JSON files I've checked multiple times. Every time when I start the game all directions are set to default. Thanks for help!

P.S. I cheacked Minecraft original BlockFurnace, but it confused me instead of helping.

Here is the code that I already have:

```
public class DirBlock extends BlockHorizontal implements IHasModel {

public DirBlock(String name) {
    super(Material.CLOTH);
    setSoundType(SoundType.CLOTH);
    setCreativeTab(Main.RM_TAB1);
    setUnlocalizedName(name);
    setRegistryName(name);
    setDefaultState(this.blockState.getBaseState().withProperty(FACING, EnumFacing.NORTH));

    ModBlocks.BLOCKS.add(this);
    ModItems.ITEMS.add(new ItemBlock(this).setRegistryName(this.getRegistryName()));
}

public static final PropertyDirection FACING = PropertyDirection.create("facing", EnumFacing.Plane.HORIZONTAL);

@Override
protected BlockStateContainer createBlockState() {
    return new BlockStateContainer(this, new IProperty[] { FACING });
}

@Override
public IBlockState getStateFromMeta(int meta) {
    return getDefaultState().withProperty(FACING, meta == 0 ? EnumFacing.WEST : EnumFacing.EAST);
}

@Override
public int getMetaFromState(IBlockState state) {
    EnumFacing facing = (EnumFacing) state.getValue(FACING);
    return facing.getHorizontalIndex();
}

@Override
public IBlockState getStateForPlacement(World world, BlockPos pos, EnumFacing facing, float hitX, float hitY,
    float hitZ, int meta, EntityLivingBase placer, EnumHand hand) {
return super.getStateForPlacement(world, pos, facing, hitX, hitY, hitZ, meta, placer, hand).withProperty(FACING, placer.getHorizontalFacing());
}

@Override
public void registerModels() {
    Main.proxy.registerItemRenderer(Item.getItemFromBlock(this), 0, "inventory");
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Your `metaFromState` and `stateFromMeta` functions are not mirrors <sub><sup>(And they should be)</sup></sub>

```
@Override
public IBlockState getStateFromMeta(int meta) {
    return getDefaultState().withProperty(FACING, meta == 0 ? EnumFacing.WEST : EnumFacing.EAST);
}

@Override
public int getMetaFromState(IBlockState state) {
    EnumFacing facing = (EnumFacing) state.getValue(FACING);
    return facing.getHorizontalIndex();
}
```

You're using the facing index for encoding to metadata, but when you come back, you make a determination on if the metadata is exactly 0, and if so, facing is WEST (and all other values mean EAST).

Unfortunately, WEST is not 0.  This, from the in-code Javadoc for `getHorizontalIndex()`:

```
/**
 * Get the index of this horizontal facing (0-3). The order is S-W-N-E
 */
```

You should be using this:

```
//use existing getMetaFromState
@Override
public IBlockState getStateFromMeta(int meta)
{
    return this.getDefaultState().withProperty(FACING, EnumFacing.getHorizontal(meta));
}
```

If you want your block to only ever face EAST and WEST (and never NORTH/SOUTH) then you should enforce that on block placed and then encode using a single bit of metadata:

```
//use existing getStateFromMeta
@Override
public int getMetaFromState(IBlockState state) {
    EnumFacing facing = (EnumFacing) state.getValue(FACING);
    return facing == EnumFacing.WEST?0:1;
}
```

Comment: The directions now work perfectly, even when reload the world. But now there's still one problem I can't figure out. JSON files are valid, but the block is still black and purple cube. What shoud I do?

Comment: @RJprogrammer That is the result of a invalid (or missing) blockstate.json, invalid (or missing) model.json, or invalid (or missing) texture files. Check the log for errors.